# Error get static file from another project

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm on Network project but when I runserver this project, it get static file from my another project is Mail, static file in Network project still work ok, but it appear error in my Terminal and I don't know how to solve it !

```
Network
|-static
    |-network
        |-style.css
        |-index.js
```

`[21/Feb/2022 12:22:48] ←[33m"GET /static/mail/inbox.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1667←[0m`

setting.py

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clarify what "Network" is? I think it comes from CS5W, hello classmate.
I think you need to distinguish the `STATIC_URL` vs `STATIC_ROOT`.
You can find in the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL